# Select2 Country – Save text not id in $_POST

Tags: jquery, post, jquery-select2, country

I have an selectbox replacement for countries with the jQuery Plugin select2.

**jQuery**

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var isoCountries = [
        { id: 'QA', text: 'Qatar',},
        { id: 'CA', text: 'Canada'},
        { id: 'CN', text: 'China'},
        { id: 'DE', text: 'Germany'},
        { id: 'RU', text: 'Russia'},
        { id: 'IT', text: 'Italy'}
        ];

        $("[data-type='country']").select2({
            placeholder: "Select a country",
            data: isoCountries
        });
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">    
    <label for="country–32" id="label_country–32" class="control-label">Country *</label>
    <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" id="country–32" name="country–32" data-type="country" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <input type="submit" name="validatesubmit" value="Please validate" class="btn btnPrimary span-2 push-8">
</form>
```

–––
Generated select-formfield:

```
<select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" id="country–32" name="country–32" data-type="country" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    country        
    <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="CN">China</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
    <option value="RU">Russia</option>
    <option value="IT">Italy</option>

    …

</select>
```

My problem now is that if I send the form it save the id (CountryISO Shortname) as value in `$_POST` and not text (Countryname). How can I change this?

Best regards,
Jan

EDIT:
Here you can download the country-list with identically id and text:
https://gist.github.com/janstieler/c715254d7d2994b80a74a37bb29e4439

Comment: can you show form code too? as well as AJAX if you're using it to submit data

Comment: either you also have to use text in replacement of id or either you need to use jquery to get the text from the dropdown like this
jQuery("[name='market'] option:selected").text();

Comment: Attention, I changed the selector in my post an added the html form.

Comment: you want to get text instead of value in `$_POST`, right?

Comment: Yes. $_Post saves the value and than I got this also in my form output.
But this should be readable by human an no one can read the ISO-Shortcodes.

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik Thanks! I thought about this solution but than I thought a programmatically solution would be nicer than lost information.
For a faster solution I will do it on this way but if someone have another idea how i can solve this programmatically don't be shy to write a comment :).

Comment: you can have one hidden field which stores text of options so you'll get both key and value of the option.